# No CUDA GPUs are available

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

i get this error from the method during the model training process. i am using the google colab to run the code. the google colab dont have any GPU. Is their any other way i can make the code run without requiring cuda cpu.

How can i fix this error ?

```
def train_model(model, train_loader, val_loader, epoch, loss_function, optimizer, path, early_stop):
   
    # GPU
   #device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
#     device = torch.device("cpu")
    device = torch.device("cuda")
    model = model.to(device)
    

    patience, eval_loss = 0, 0
    
    # train
    for i in range(epoch):
        total_loss, count = 0, 0
        y_pred = list()
        y_true = list()
        for idx, (x, y) in tqdm(enumerate(train_loader), total=len(train_loader)):
            x, y = x.to(device), y.to(device) 
            u, m = model(x)
            predict = torch.sigmoid(torch.sum(u*m, 1))
            y_pred.extend(predict.cpu().detach().numpy())
            y_true.extend(y.cpu().detach().numpy())
            loss = loss_function(predict, y.float())
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            total_loss += float(loss)
            count += 1
            
        train_auc = roc_auc_score(np.array(y_true), np.array(y_pred))
        torch.save(model, path.format(i+1))
        print("Epoch %d train loss is %.3f and train auc is %.3f" % (i+1, total_loss / count, train_auc))
    
        # verify
        total_eval_loss = 0
        model.eval()
        count_eval = 0
        val_y_pred = list()
        val_true = list()
        for idx, (x, y) in tqdm(enumerate(val_loader), total=len(val_loader)):
            x, y = x.to(device), y.to(device)
            u, m = model(x)
            predict = torch.sigmoid(torch.sum(u*m, 1))
            val_y_pred.extend(predict.cpu().detach().numpy())
            val_true.extend(y.cpu().detach().numpy())
            loss = loss_function(predict, y.float())
            total_eval_loss += float(loss)
            count_eval += 1
        val_auc = roc_auc_score(np.array(y_true), np.array(y_pred))
        print("Epoch %d val loss is %.3fand train auc is %.3f" % (i+1, total_eval_loss / count_eval, val_auc))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the line where you create your `torch.device()` and remove all the `.to(device)` functions where you use it. Then you also don't need to write `.cpu().detach()` also. You can simply write `predict.numpy()` as such. When you write `device = torch.device("cuda")` you are creating a GPU device and you are then transferring your model and data into the GPU device when its not available. This is the reason for the error.

Comment: but if i remove the `device = torch.device("cuda")` it will affect the ` x, y = x.to(device), y.to(device)` line in the code.

Comment: You can remove those lines of code. Those lines just transfers your x and y from CPU to GPU. You can even remove the line `model = model.to(device)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. i did made those changes and it works.

Comment: You're welcome. You can then mark my answer as accepted. Thanks!